# Links to illustrate questions that point to non-english websites?

Tags: discussion, questions, hyperlinks, citations

I'm not really sure about this, but the main language of this site seems to be english (I'm not a native speaker myself). I've just posted a [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4189/have-any-mark-brandis-novels-ever-been-released-in-english-language) regarding alleged english translations of a german author. All links to websites I could give were in german. If only 1% of readers could actually read them, should I rather leave them out to not offend people that don't speak german?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should feel free to link to sources in any language. It would be helpful to pull relevant quotes from the text into your answer/question and translate them. People can always pass the page through one of many web page translation services across the web.

If some people are offended by other languages and cultures, we don't want them here anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In this case there's not really anything I could quote, I just linked to those pages since they provide background information on the author and on the series in question, but I can't think of anything that specifically would help answering that particular question.

Comment: @takrl: there must be something on those pages that made you want to link to them. That would be good to quote. But quotes aren't really necessary, they are just helpful.

Comment: Well, mainly I placed those links because those pages provide background on the series and the author, but there's nothing specifically that would help answering this particular question. I figured that most probably the author is not well known, or not known at all, outside of germany.